# How to build a utf8 string in python

Tags: python, string, utf-8

I know how to build a string with variables by doing something like this

```
'this is a {!s} {!}'.format('simple','example')
```

But I couldn't get this to work if one of the variables has a utf8 character. It tells me that 'ascii' codec can't encode character  . . .

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  Could you give an example of a failed attempt to get UTF-8 to work (including how you're printing the result out)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
u'this is a {} {}'.format(u'привет', u'мир')
```

As an alternative for Python2.7 you may import `unicode_literals` from `__future__` to mark all strings as unicode by default. In this case to mark some string as ASCII you need to prefix it with `b`:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> 'this is a {} {}'.format('привет', 'мир')
u'this is a \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u043c\u0438\u0440'
```